# When should I use templated parameters versus construction parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am implementing a class called `FingerprintBuffer` that is to store fingerprints. Each fingerprint is essentially just a byte array. The size of each fingerprint and the capacity of the buffer is **fixed** and **already known** at **compile time**. I have two options:

Templated parameters:

```
template <int FNGPRT_SIZE, int BUFFER_CAP>
class FingerprintBuffer {
 public:
  FingerprintBuffer() {
    buff_ = new char[FNGPRT_SIZE * BUFFER_CAP]();
    size_ = 0;
  }

 private:
  char* buff_;
  int size_;
};

FingerprintBuffer<36, 300> fngprt_buff;
```

Or constructor parameters:

```
class FingerprintBuffer {
 public:
  FingerprintBuffer(int fngprt_sz, int buff_cap) {
    fngprt_sz_ = fngprt_sz;
    buff_cap_ = buff_cap
    buff_ = new char[fngprt_sz_ * buff_cap_]();
    size_ = 0;
  }

 private:
  int fngprt_sz_;
  int buff_cap_;
  char* buff_;
  int size_;
};

FingerprintBuffer fngprt_buff(36, 300);
```

Which option should I go for? And generally speaking under which conditions / assumptions I should choose templated parameters over construction parameters?

Comment: Obvious pros for templated class: you don't need to store `fngprt_sz_` and `buff_cap_` and you can make some preprocessing calculations if you need (btw it doesn't look so). Obvious cons: if there are lots of different fingerprints by size or capacity, compilation time is longer and you need more code to provide operations with fingerprints of different types.

Comment: And for example `std::array`'s size is fixed, because it's allocated on the stack, not on the heap.

Comment: In the first example you're not taking advantage of the fact that the values are constants. `buff_` can be a static array (`char buff_[FNGPRT_SIZE * BUFFER_CAP]`)

Comment: This question is essentially answered by understanding the differences between `std::array` and `std::vector`. Most significant is one's size is a compile time constant while the other is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give your a common usage. That is if you param like `FNGPRT_SIZE` will not change in the runtime, you can use template param. If you param will change at runtime, you must use function param.

Also, a template param can save memory (struct size smaller) and get const number Optimization by compiler.

Usually, template param can also give you a compile time check. If you implement a matrix multiplay, you can use template param with `static_assert(COL_NUM, ROW_NUM)` for two matrix. You can find errors in early time.